# How to add an icon to electron application

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I've got my electron build files for a win .exe and installer but the icons aren't mine. In my main.js file, I have code to attach the icon but I can only make it work inside of the createWindow function. Outside the function, I get an error message. The .exe will run and I get my icon, though it's I get an error in doing so; the installer won't work at all. I've tried going through several tutorials but none of them solve this problem.

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Tray} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let win

function createWindow () {
  const appIcon = new Tray('icon/app.png')
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1920, height: 1080, icon: 'icon/app.ico' })
  console.log(appIcon, win)
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'app/app.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MyApp",
  "private": true,
  "main": "main.js",
  "build": {
    "appID": "myapp",
    "productName": "MyApp",
    "icon": "icon/app.ico"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ." ,
    "package": "",
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.1"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Do you want to replace to default app icon or something else in particular?

Comment: I want my icon to replace the default in all locations.

Comment: Any idea why electron app is not opening window automatically on system startup in windows tabmode but, working perfect in desktop mode?

Answer (score 7):

> Simple solution

```
const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage;
    var image = nativeImage.createFromPath(__dirname + '/public/img/logo.png'); 
 // where public folder on the root dir

    image.setTemplateImage(true);


 // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1179,
        height: 754,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        transparent: false,
        icon: image
    })
```

Comment: This worked for me. Did not need to use `image.setTemplateImage(true);`.

Comment: On several places it says that using a path string is enough. But just until I used nativeImage got it working on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

inside the main.js

`mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600,icon: __dirname + '/icon.ico'});`

and on the installer, if you are using electron-builder

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.15",
    "electron-builder": "^12.3.1"
  },
```

make a folder on the root and named **build** inside that folder add your icon.ico

sometimes you need to restart the electron or build the app 2 times

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me. To display the app icon in the taskbar, you can update the icon on the fly in main.js (if using typescript then main.ts)

```
win.setIcon(path.join(__dirname, '/src/assets/logo-small.png'));
```

Worth to mention `__dirname` points to same directory as package.json